# Who set a bounty over Riddick in "Riddick" (2013)?

Tags: plot-explanation, riddick

In simple words, how can Riddick be in the same time:

- a Lord Marshal of the (most likely most powerful in the universe) Necromonger fleet and
- wanted convict with a huge bounty promised for his head (twice as much for bringing him dead)?

Who could set up such bounty? How could any mercenary wish to set sails for hunting leader of the powerful nation?

Comment: I don't really understand where the conflict is here. He is a convict that happened to become leader of a large fleet. The Necromongers don't really care for some random planet systems' arrest warrants, nor does becoming leader of the Necromongers suddenly annull your crimes in another jurisdiction. Maybe he's harder to capture now, but so what? Noone said capturing criminals would be easy, nor are you forced to do so as a mercenary.

Comment: In January of 2020 Business Insider reporter that an Iranian MP put a $3M bounty on Donald Trump's head. There is nothing stopping somewhere in far away land (planet) to put a bounty on who they want.

Comment: I think that both of your comments can be crafted into a nicely working answer, as they're explaining what I am asking for.

Comment: Wasn’t there an arrest warrant issued on Saddam Hussein. It took an entire army to collect on it. The Necromongers have their own large, effective army to protect their leader. And, no Necromonger would have an incentive to collect on Riddick’s bounty since that could potentially make killing him by a Necromonger difficult. It would be a larger incentive to kill Riddick themselves and become leader of the Necromongers. At which point, the amount of the bounty would be meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the graphic novel, Riddick is an escaped convict. Since he is a convict that has escaped, the authorities of the prison would issue a bounty for his return. His status as leader of a warring nation would not effect this. It would just make the bounty hunters job more difficult if not impossible.

Comment: I think that a bounty should be issued by some "rich man" or "someone deeply involved" rather than "prison's authorities". I don't quite believe that a regular prison, it's authorities or even some government would have that amount of money (thousands or even millions) for each, even very special convict. Especially that bringing him to that prison wouldn't gave "authorities" any return for paid bounty. We can see this clearly in "Chronicles of Riddick" where it is imam (a sole person) who issues a bounty. But that's just my opinion. I'm accepting your answer as last sencence explains all.

Answer (score 2):

[Vaako](https://riddick.fandom.com/wiki/Vaako).

- Riddick's refusal to swear into the Necromonger faith causes dissent and assassination attempts.
- Vaako is motivated to become Lord Marshal and transcend.
- Vaako leaves him on "not Furya".

Although it is not directly shown, Vaako would then place the bounty and give the bounty hunters his location.

Comment: The director's cut version of "Riddick" that ends on Necromonger's ship. It is revealed in last scene that it was not Vaako, but Krone, who betrayed Riddick and sent him to "not Furya". Krone says: "You misunderstand. Vaako is a decent man
who meant to honor his word. Even with you, strangely. I don't care about Furya. I don't care what the pact was between you and him. This faith cannot have a misbeliever or a kind heart leading it, and I have done what I have done to ensure...". So, Vaako, honouring his words and willing to sent Riddick to Furya, wouldn't most likely set a bounty on him.